# How to run an ongoing terminal command and have vim open

Tags: vim, terminal, nodemon, simplehttpserver, neovim

I do a lot of vim and terminal work. It would be great if I could run a terminal command like `http-server` or `nodemon` and then go into vim, make edits in multiplte buffers and quickly switch to look at my terminal for http-server output or nodemon logs, and then switch back to vim.

What is an easy what to do this?

I'm trying to decide between neovim's terminal emulator, I can't quite get `ctrl` + `z` and fg to work for me, because putting http-server in the background stops it's function for some reason.

Any other suggestions are welcome too. Ideally I could view my terminal in just another vim buffer.

Comment: Use a terminal multiplexer like tmux or screen.

Comment: vote to close should be on superuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exit neovim's terminal mode with `<C-\><C-n>` (ctrl-backslash followed by ctrl-n), which puts you back in normal mode with any processes still running.

I have it mapped to a slightly more convenient key combination (ctrl-left bracket twice):

```
tnoremap <C-[><C-[> <C-\><C-n>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want to do, but would [tmux](https://gist.github.com/MohamedAlaa/2961058) be what you want?

Another good [link](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tmux-crash-course)

Comment: Not really, but this is an interesting way to go : )

Answer (score 1):

Try [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) vim plugin:

> Conque is a Vim plugin which allows you to run interactive programs,
>   such as bash on linux or powershell.exe on Windows, inside a Vim
>   buffer. In other words it is a terminal emulator which uses a Vim
>   buffer to display the program output.